# How can I change a style attribute of a div in a view on mouse click?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a backbone view, that is listening to a mouse click event like this:

```
...[code before]...
events: {
   mousedown: "catchMouseClick"
},
...[code after]...
```

in "catchMouseClick" I'll create a new View like this

```
...[code before]...
catchMouseClick: function(e) {
    //Initialize RightClickMenu
    this.rightClickMenu = new RightClickMenu({mouseX:e.pageX,mouseY:e.pageY});
    this.rightClickMenu.remove();                        
},
...[code after]...
```

As you can see, I use pageX and pageY from my mouse click event "e" as parameters to create RightClickMenu

And finally here's my RightClickMenu View:

```
var RightClickMenu = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:$('#outerDiv'),
  render: function(){
   $(this.el).append(_.template($('#rightClickTemplate').html()));
   $('#rightClickMenuDiv').css('top',this.options.mouseY);
   $('#rightClickMenuDiv').css('left',this.options.mouseX);
 }
});
```

I use a a template "called" rightClickTemplate with a div having the id "rightClickMenuDiv".

My question is, what other path could I possibly run? Because I don't want to have to many jQuery selectors in my source code at this place.

Maybe I could handle these parameters in my template? Something like this (source not tested):

```
<script type="text/template" id="rightClickTemplate">
  <div id="rightClickMenuDiv" style="top:<%= mouseY =>, left:<%= mouseX=>">
  ...
  </div>
</script>
```

So I could pass them in while loading the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimize use of jquery selector,

```
var RightClickMenu = Backbone.View.extend({

  el:$('#outerDiv'),

  template : _.template($('#rightClickTemplate').html()),

  render: function(){
      this.rightMenuDiv = $(this.template()).appendTo(this.el);
      this.updatePosition(this.options.mouseX, this.options.mouseY);
      return this;
  },

 updatePosition : function(x, y){
      this.rightMenuDiv.css({
           top : y,
           left : x
      });
 } 

});
```

try this for upade position on mouse click

```
...[code before]...
render : function(){
     this.rightClickMenu = new RightClickMenu({mouseX:0, mouseY:0});
     return this;
},

catchMouseClick: function(e) {
    //Initialize RightClickMenu
    this.rightClickMenu.updatePosition(mouseX:e.pageX,mouseY:e.pageY);                
},
...[code after].
```

..